# Probability when making random pairs from an array of numbers

Tags: probability

Let's say I have an array of unique values such as $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)$.

And I want to create pairs randomly from them like this: $(8,4)$, $(5,2)$, $(7,1)$, $(6,3)$. I want to know if I make another pairing between them what is the probability for a value to be paired again with it's previous match?

Some specifications: $(8,4) and $(4,8) are 1 pair, not two. Also you cannot make pairs like (1,1), (2,2).

Comment: You'll find it difficult to get a pair with $(7,1)$, because $7$ isn't in your original array.

Comment: I've edited my question by including 7. However it doesn't count what numbers are there.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly 1/(n-1), as your question is in the end "what are the probabilites of picking this number in this set of number".

You have to convince yourself that it doesn't depend of previous pairings : the thought "if (5,2) is already a pair, then the probability to do the pair (7,1) is higher than 1/7" is true, but has nothing to do here !

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have an array $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$, so it has $n$ unique elements. (If the elements are all unique, we often call this a set.)

Picking a particular integer $x$ from the array has probability $\frac1n$. If you take the array again and then pick a particular integer $y$, then every choice of $y$ also has a probability of $\frac1n$. So the probability that $y=x$ is $\frac1n \cdot \frac1n$. But your array has $n$ integers, so there are $n$ ways to do this, so we have, by the [product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), $n \cdot \frac1n \cdot \frac1n = \frac{n}{n} \cdot \frac1n = \frac1n$.

So the probability of twice picking the same element from an array of $n$ unique elements is $\frac1n$.

Comment: But I would like to know the probability for x to be paired again with y, and not the probability for y to be x.

Comment: The events are independent. Your array does not remember previous pairings.

Comment: Try n=2. Your prediction is 50% but the answer is 100%. Ergo, something is wrong.

Comment: @Did for $n=2$, potential pairs are $\{(1,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,1)\}$. The probability of a pair of form $(a,a)$ occurring is clearly $0.5$, unless I've totally misunderstood something.

Comment: Pairings are made of pairs of distinct elements, subsets of size 2 if you prefer. Hence there is only one pairing of the set {1,2}, which is itself.

Comment: Yes: if $1$ is paired with $2$, i.e. we pick $(1,2)$ on our first try, and then we proceed to our second try, we pick a $1$ again, then we want to pick another $2$ such that we get the pair $(1,2)$ again. The probability of picking another $2$ is $\frac12$. Have I dramatically misread the question?

Comment: "The probability of picking another 2 is..." 100%, actually.

Comment: @Did why is the probability of picking another $2$ 100%? The set is $\{1,2\}$, so we can pick either $1$ or $2$, so we have $p=0.5$.

Comment: Noooooo... One makes PAIRS, hence one picks a NEW element.

Comment: Blah. To be fair, that was absolutely not apparent from the question when I answered it. It is not implicit at all that 'pairs' may not reuse elements... (see e.g. Cartesian Cross Product, etc.)

Comment: Let us take the case when n = 4, you say that we have (1,2),(1,3), (1,4) as the pairings ( 3 pairings) Are you saying that if 2 is the first value, the pairings are (2,1),(2,3),(2,4) Still three.  For any given value in the array, there can only be n-1 pairings.  Is this the logic that you should apply? This is not at all stated in the problem!!

Comment: I was thinking in this line, For n = 4, the pairings could be (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4). If one of these is chosen, say (2,3), 2 could be paired with 1,3,4 and 3 could be paired with 1,4 (as (2,3) and (3,2) are the same) and that we have five possible pairing opportunities in the second try and that the prob = 1/( (4-1)+(4-2)) = 1/5, For any n, it is (2n-3) and hence the probability is 1/(2n-3)  - Instead of 1/(n-1).  Let me know if it is flat out wrong?  I used to be a chess player, this is what pairing meant...

Answer (score 0):

No of ways you could make a pair from the array is 8C2 = 28. Suppose you choose a pair (x,y) in the first time around, the probability that in the second try ( does not remember what was chosen in the first try), you choose the same pair is 1/28.  Extending it to any n, the probability that one chooses the same pair from an array {1,2,....n} in two successive tries is $1/(^{n}C{_2})$

Comment: The number of way is incorrect in this case because I want the pair to be from non-repetitive values. For example you can't make a pair like (1, 1). Also (1, 2) and (2, 1) is just 1 pair, not two.

Comment: In which case you may have to change n^2 to nC2.  That  is it!

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Did, why do you think so?. If has a pair that is non-repetitive that should be chosen then the way to choose is nC2.  Second time around, he changes his rule of picking (1,1), (2,2); yeah in which case you solution is a bit tricky. The fact remains that the second time around does not depend on the first try so that is no  conditional probability.  The array is fixed

Comment: There exists 3 pairings of a set of size 4. You predict 1/6, which is the chance, when one performs two pairings and chooses randomly a pair from each, that these are the same pair. The question asks for the chance that some given element, say 1, is paired with the same element in both pairings, which is 1/3. (But I agree the formulation of the question is a tad ambiguous...)

Comment: I misunderstood the question as it was not clear.  If you chose (8,2) in the first pairing, which of 8, or 2 would you choose to the the given element?